# Why does passing props cause it to be embed inside an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is there a way to pass a prop without embedding it inside the object?

For instance, consider the parent component passing the "partners" data

```
const partners = [
  {
    name: "Test1",
  },
  {
    name: "Test2",
  },
  {
    name: "Test3",
  },
  {
    name: "Test4",
  },
];

const Partners: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <PartnerPanel props={partners} />
    </>
  );
};
```

The child component

```
// incorrect type 
type PropsType = [
  {
    name: string;
  }
];

//correct type
type PropsType =  { props: { name: string; }[]; }


export const PartnerPanel: FC<PropsType> = (props): JSX.Element => {
  return <div>{props.props[0].name}</div>;
};
```

Why is it that the props are embedded inside another props, for instance, I have to do `props.props[0].name` to get the value? Instead of `props[0].name`

Comment: Because component props are already an object. When you write `const PartnerPanel = (props) =>` `props` is the component props object _and within that_ you have an object with a `props` key.

Comment: You have a variable named `props`, and on that variable you have a property named `props`.  Your object structure has these names because you've given it these names.  You (1) don't need the variable, you can destructure directly in the function parameters and (2) don't need to name the property `props` but can (and are encouraged to) give it a meaningful name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nested props object is something you are doing, not something that happens automatically with props.

You have named a prop - `props`

`<PartnerPanel props={partners} />`

This is a confusing name. You should probably rename it to be clearer as `partners`.

`<PartnerPanel partners={partners} />`

Then you would access it more logically as

```
export const PartnerPanel: FC<PropsType> = (props): JSX.Element => {
  return <div>{props.partners[0].name}</div>;
};
```

You will also need to change your type

```
type PropsType =  { partners: { name: string; }[]; }
```